# Display all messaging apps installed in Android phone

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to show all messaging apps installed by user in it's phone. The list I am expecting is like, WhatsApp, Facebook messenger, Viber, Slack, Skype, WeChat etc (If any installed). So, far I have tried getting all apps in Phone through this code:

```
        val pm: PackageManager = context!!.packageManager
        val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
        val lst = pm.queryIntentActivities(i, 0)

        for (resolveInfo in lst) {
            Log.d(
                "Test",
                "New Launcher Found: " + resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName
            )
```

This only gives me Slack app but not other messaging apps. I have a feeling it has something to do with MIME types as mentioned in Google docs.

```
text/*, senders will often send text/plain, text/rtf, text/html, text/json
image/*, senders will often send image/jpg, image/png, image/gif
video/*, senders will often send video/mp4, video/3gp
```

but I don't know how to use this info. Any help would be appreciated. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

add `ACTION_SENDTO`as action parameter while creating your intent and you should see the list of apps capable of handling messages/sms etc.

`val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
// get list of activities that can handle this type of intent
val lst = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)`

Comment: I do want to send data but I need to know the list of all messaging apps first, like, com.Slack, com.viber.voip, so that I can show them the way I want.

Comment: you can pass the same intent object in `pm.queryIntentActivities(i, 0` to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Here pack name refers to - apps package name

```
   fun appinstalled(){
    var app_names = mutableListOf<String>()
    val app_package = mutableListOf<String>()
    val packagelist: MutableList<PackageInfo> =  packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)
    var appname : String
    var packname : String


    for (i in packagelist.indices) {
        val packageinfo : PackageInfo= packagelist[i]


        appname=packageinfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString()
        packname=packageinfo.packageName
        app.add(appname)
        app-package.add(packname)




    }
```

this will the list of app installed in the user device as well as their package name . After this attach these list to the Listview and their adpater and all done.

Comment: If you face any Isuue comment below

Comment: Thanks @DikShU , no offense, but the question was about getting messaging apps, or the apps which have messaging abilities like Fb messenger, viber, etc., the code which you have mentioned above is for the complete apps list in device.  There are tons of same solution already available for getting all apps. In short, Please read the question, this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @androidStud for this you can compare 2 list and make a common list from there as 1st list contains all app name and other you have to make a list that conatins all Social messaging app names and then combine and compare the both

Comment: I was looking for a generic solution. Every now and then there comes a new messaging app in the market, so making a static list is not a feasible solution, but anyways I have found the solution by looking into the permission of apps and identifying whether it's a messaging app or not.

Comment: If You found any solution Please update here the Solution